# ImageMagick delegate library error

Tags: imagemagick, gif, postscript

I have recently installed ImageMagick and I am trying to use it to convert postscript files to .gif images. I ran the post installation test:

```
/usr/local/bin/convert logo: logo.gif
```

This works perfectly, but trying to convert my own does not. I am using a CentOS virtual machine.

This is what I first tried:

```
/usr/local/bin/convert Average.ps: average.gif
```

Nothing seems to happen, it's as if something is happening but nothing does.

Then I tried:

```
convert -list configure
```

I did this to see what files types are supported, I got:

```
DELEGATES mpeg ps
```

So I tried:

```
/usr/local/bin/convert Average.ps: average.mpeg
```

And the same thing happens. I also tried the above without the .ps just in case that would help.

When I run

```
display /root/Desktop/Average_1961.ps
```

I get this error:

> display: delegate library support not built-in `' (X11) @ error/display.c/DisplayImageCommand/1906.

But the delegate library shows .ps and .mpeg support, and the install test created a gif, so I'm very confused.

Has anyone got any suggestions?

Thanks,
Ciara

Comment: What's your CentOS and ImageMagick version (`convert -version`)?

Comment: Hi,

It's the lastest release of ImageMagick: 6.8.8-7 Q16 i686.
And it's CentOS 5.7.

Thanks,
Ciara